# Use Mean Value Theorem to establish that $7 \frac{1}{4} < \sqrt{53} < 7 \frac{2}{7}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am working on the following question from Lay's Introduction to Analysis with Proof:

> Use the Mean Value Theorem to establish that $7 \frac{1}{4} < \sqrt{53} < 7 \frac{2}{7}$

My work so far:

Define $f(t) = \sqrt t$ which we will work with on the interval $[49, 53]$ as $\sqrt{53} \sim \sqrt{49} = 7$.

By MVT,

$$(53-49)\frac{1}{2\sqrt x} = \sqrt{53} - \sqrt{49}$$

Now, $x \in [49, 53]$ so that $49 < x < 53 \Rightarrow 7 < \sqrt x < \sqrt{53} < 8 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{4} < \sqrt{53} - 7 < \frac{2}{7}$

So I have obtained the bound
$$ \frac{1}{4} + 7 < \sqrt{53} < \frac{2}{7} + 7$$
but don't know how to proceed as to  show that $7 \frac{1}{4} < \sqrt{53} < 7 \frac{2}{7}$.

Comment: You have proven exactly what you need. What else do you want?

Comment: I need to show that $7 \frac{1}{4} < \sqrt{53} < 7 \frac{2}{7}$, I haven't proven that, only the inequality above.

Comment: The infamous mixed fraction $7 \frac{1}{4}$ means $7 + \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: I cannot imagine what you though $7\,\frac14$ means other than $7+\frac14$.

Comment: Okay I am dumb - I thought it meant $7 \times 1 / 4 = 7 / 4$. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I don't like this exercise. It would be easier to just square the bounds.

Comment: In fairness, I don't think this means you are dumb. I think it means that mixed fractions are terrible.

Comment: I agree with Gregory. It is just terrible notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$7\frac{1}{4}=7+\frac{1}{4}$$
and
$$7\frac{2}{7}=7+\frac{2}{7}$$

Comment: That is because $7\frac{1}{4}=(7*4+1)/4$. Analogous with the other fraction.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that comment. This is the definition. The reason it is $(7\cdot 4+1)/4$ is that $7 =(7\cdot 4)/4$, with addition of fractions requiring common denominator.